What was I thinking when I drew this diagram?
True story which I thought worth sharing: I recently came across a scrawled diagram on a scrap piece of paper while tidying my house. It was clearly my handiwork (probably a rough idea for a puzzle), consisting of an arrangement of letters and arrows, and I had absolutely no idea why I had considered it worth creating.
However, I gave it a little thought and soon smiled as I realised what I had been playing around with. I wonder whether you might be able to work it out too?
I have reproduced the diagram here (much more neatly than I had originally scrawled it) but - to make it more of a puzzle for you - I have obfuscated the 5 English vowels (A, E, I, O and U) and their 'special friend' Y with question marks. The challenge for you is to put them in the right places, and explain why they belong there...

TASK: Explain the arrangement of letters and arrows in the diagram and which of the question marks should be replaced by A, E, I, O, U and Y. What was I playing about with when I constructed this diagram?



This represents

 the NATO Phonetic Alphabet.

More specifically,

 Each letter points to the last letter of its corresponding NATO phonetic alphabet word:
 


Aside from the Case of the Vanishing Shakespearean Title Character, this is exactly correct, yes :) Out of interest, how long did it take for the penny to drop for you, and what gave it away?

I've seen this exact graph before! rot13(uggcf://chmmyr.havirefvgl/chmmyr/p-vf-sbe-pybfvat-oryy.ugzy)

Wow, interesting - I had no idea this had been done before! Nothing new under the sun, hey?
